# How do I open a file on Android using C# and Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
 intent.SetType("text/plain");                
 intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
 StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select file"), 1);
```

This code works to a extent. I can move around the folders, but as soon as I select a file, the procedure closes and we're back to app. Nothing happens.

How can I select a file and then have it loaded into the app? The app has a control which can hold the data once it's read in.

Comment: Not sure if you've read the latest documentation on the Android Dev site: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as Android changed how to handle files since Xamarin started (and Xamarin is set for EOL 2024). If you still intend to use Xamarin on a recent Android OS I would look at any Android Storage Access Framework plugin/library.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll definitely check it all out.

Comment: I tried this:

var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
intent.AddCategory (Intent.CategoryOpenable);
StartActivityForResult (Intent.CreateChooser (intent, "Select file"), 0);

BUT I click on the "Open" button,  the words "Select File" do not appear. I can move from folder to folder and see the files listed but when click on on, the windows closes and nothing happens. Is opening a file on Android this difficult?

Comment: I added these lines:  intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
                intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true);
                intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true);

What I need to do is look at the data in the file before copying it into my program.

Comment: What I need to do is look at the data in the file before copying it into my program. If the data's text I do one thing; if not text, something else. But after I select a file, the window closes.

Comment: While you can select for certain MIME types, if you need to look inside the file, you'll need a copy of the file under your app's control. Also you should state how you are expecting to get the file (even if it is a copy of Xamarian documentation) or which library you are using along with any error messages.